# How to view Amazon movies from 14.04

Tags: 14.04, video-player

I was not allowed to respond to "Recommended Method to Watch Amazon Prime using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS" but I think my question refers to that answer. I don't know what HAL is or DRM. I'm just a poor, Linux-ignorant user who finally escaped from Microsoft prison after 40 years and just wants to play movies on my new Linux laptop.

Possibly I just need clarification. I just installed 14.04 LTS. From "Recommended..." I get the impression that I can't watch Amazon instant movies and that there is nothing I can do about it. Yes? Really? I have to open the dreaded and hated laptop with Windows 8.1 in order to watch movies in bed??? So much for my planned campaign to convert my friends and family...

Comment: Amazon Prime supports Flash and Silverlight. Flash worked for me on Amazon Prime under 12.04 LTS. Workarounds for 14.04 LTS seem to work for some people, and not for others. None of them have worked for me so far.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use amazon prime, but I know someone who does and I've seen it used before. The way I saw it done was through amazon.com, just go to the prime tab (sign in of course) and to prime instant video, your library should show up there.

And I've no idea what HAL is (other than the computer from 2001 A Space Odyssey), but DRM is Digital Rights Management and attempts to prevent piracy (not very successfully).

Answer (score 0):

This procedure worked for me after upgrading from 12.04 LTS to 14.04 LTS. I tried a great many workarounds before trying this one. I don't know whether this procedure alone will work, but I plan to try it in a VM later this week.

First, [I installed the HAL from a particular PPA](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/10/fixing-amazon-prime-streaming-drm-protected-flash-13-10).

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mjblenner/ppa-hal
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install hal
```

Next, I [reset the license files](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager08.html). I considered this to be completely safe in my own case, because I don't have any protected content. But the linked page includes this caution.

> Be careful when resetting license files. When you reset license files,
>   Flash Player resets all existing license files for protected content
>   that plays on your computer in Flash Player. You will not be able to
>   access the content in Flash Player from this computer until you have
>   downloaded new licenses from your content provider.